# Making (server) directory public (http download)

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

tl;dr - How do I make a folder and its contents publicly readable?

I've installed and set up vsftpd on my Ubuntu VPS. Didn't realise the original intent of FTP was that only other logged in users can view/access the files. So I assumed I can just link people to the URL. The ftp:// protocol works, so I know it's an access issue.

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm loving this learning curve

Comment: You can use an http (web) server to share files using `http(s)://` protocol.

Comment: Can you give me some keywords to find out how to do that with a specific directory? Thanks

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache